# Unable to select custom field of task in process builder

Tags: process-builder, custom-field, tasks, activities

I had a requirement to create custom field called **Potential** in task, since task object does not allow you to create custom field i had to create that in activity.
Now i need to use this custom field called potential in Process builder, but unfortunately i am unable to see this field in the dropdown.
Can someone help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It should be availble, Check if you are missing any permissions on the field, else it will show all the fields including Formula, Text area.